# How do I get another field in my query, which ranks the rows depending on another field

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb, libreoffice

I am currently creating a LibreOffice Base application to determine the winners of a competition. The winner is determined by the number of seconds he takes from start to finish. How do I get a placement field, which is not part of the actual table?

```
SELECT "Team_ID", "Team_Shortname", "TotalTimeInSeconds", (HERE) AS "Placement" FROM "Team"
```

I found out how to do it on a seperate query, but I don't know how to combine it, how would I get the ID in the query again?

```
"select count(*) from Team where TotalTimeInSeconds < (select TotalTimeInSeconds
from Team where Team_ID = " + teamId + ");"
```

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense now.

```
SELECT "t"."Team_ID", "t"."Team_Shortname", "t"."TotalTimeInSeconds",
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Team" WHERE "TotalTimeInSeconds" < "t"."TotalTimeInSeconds" )
AS "Placement" FROM "Team" "t"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "TotalTimeInSeconds" ASC) AS placement, 
 "Team_ID", "Team_Shortname", "TotalTimeInSeconds"
FROM "Team" ORDER BY "TotalTimeInSeconds" ASC;
```

For more reading : [Rank, Dense Rank , Row Num](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rank/)